# How do you identify the docker image an image was built from?

Tags: docker

Some time ago I built an image using, as an example, `FROM python:latest` and tagged it `something:latest`
How can I find out which python image ID was used, and any other tags that match that ID?

Eg. which tag did I build my image from?

---

I have inspected my Docker Image using [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive/) and found that it was apparently built `FROM cc59b0ca1cf21d7`.
Docker Hub seems to only search by tag rather than id, and manually looking through I cannot find any reference to cc59b0ca1cf21d7.. is cc59b0ca1cf21d7 the droid I'm looking for?

Comment: Not meaning to be snarky, but you've just discovered why `latest` is the worse thing Docker could have ever done. Once you've fixed this, my advice is *never* to use it again.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but you can use `docker inspect YOURIMAGE` and refer to the environment variables defined in that JSON. Then you will know the exact python version of the image. Then, you could pull all of the the python docker images with that version and compare their digest to the digest in `docker inspect --format='{{json .RepoDigests}} YOURIMAGE`. Maybe this does answer the question.

Comment: @SiHa Thanks, I'll time travel and pass that advice to whoever used latest as soon as I can d: I used first-person just for readability d:

Comment: @jakub Thanks (: Unfortunately python is just an example, in the real case we can't determine the image used from within an instance of it, without a whole load of trial and error ):

Comment: Ah ok, sorry to hear that. I'm not sure if it's possible, but hopefully it is.